# Facing issue while upgrading to Spring boot 2.2.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade my project spring boot version to 2.2.4 and for that, I have generated the spring boot project from https://start.spring.io/ but it is not working well. When I run the application it starts on 8080 port after stopping the project if I try to run the project again it gives the error saying port already in use. I have tried with different port and all port I can use only once unless I manually free the port using CMD. Please help here if anyone is facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem 'port already in use' but I killed tomcat process and 
  problem is solved.

Comment: Yes, that I have already done and that is the solution only for our local environment.